# TypeError: provideModuleMap is not a function ~ NestJS

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

After upgrading NestJS I'm getting the following error `TypeError: provideModuleMap is not a function`. Using NestJS for Server-Side Rendering (SSR) in Angular, combined with Angular Universal to render SSR.

Working correctly dependencies:

```
"@nestjs/common": "^6.3.1",
"@nestjs/core": "^6.3.1",
"@nestjs/ng-universal": "^1.2.0",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.3.1"
```

Updated dependencies causing error:

```
"@nestjs/common": "^6.5.2",
"@nestjs/core": "^6.5.2",
"@nestjs/ng-universal": "^2.0.0",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.5.2"
```

`nguniversal` dependencies (they don't change):

```
"@nguniversal/common": "^8.1.1",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^8.1.1",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.1.1",
"express": "^4.17.1",
```

Using Angular 8.2.0. Other files (**app.server.module.ts**, etc.) should be fine, because SSR works perfectly fine using SSR. Full error log:

```
TypeError: provideModuleMap is not a function
    at View.app.engine (C:\users\myapp\node_modules\@nestjs\ng-universal\dist\utils\setup-universal.utils.js:23:17)
    at View.render (C:\users\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\users\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\users\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\users\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at app.get (C:\users\myapp\node_modules\@nestjs\ng-universal\dist\angular-universal.module.js:60:66)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\users\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\users\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\users\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\users\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any documentation in the Nest repo, but looking at the options interface for the `AngularUniversalModule`, I tried this and got it working:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AngularUniversalModule, applyDomino } from '@nestjs/ng-universal';
import { join, resolve } from 'path';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

const config = require('config');

// Path to server bundle in dist
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('../../../../dist/server/main');

applyDomino(global, join(resolve(), `${config.Http.distDir}/client/index.html`));

@Module({
    imports: [
        AngularUniversalModule.forRoot({
            // Path to client code in dist
            viewsPath: join(resolve(), `${config.Http.distDir}/client`),
            bundle: {
                AppServerModuleNgFactory,
                LAZY_MODULE_MAP,
                provideModuleMap,
                ngExpressEngine
            }
        })
    ],
})
export class CoreModule
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for contribution, I'll take a look into my project and see. Definitely +1 for the effort to publish you answer though!

Comment: totally solved my problem, what I did is I created a nestjs cli app and an angular cli app separately (separate folders) and installed the angular libs in the backend (copied them) so when I applied ur code it all started working perfectly

Comment: @MyCompassSpins, have you tried upgrade to the newest version `4.0.1` of `@nestjs/ng-universal`? I'm having such error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined @nestjs/ng-universal`.

Comment: @DanielDanielecki, personally I've found Nest's ng-universal module to be too unwieldy so my practice is to deploy an API separate from the client application that consumes it. For my Angular SSR apps, I'll use a simple Express server. For prerendered Angular apps I have a custom Apache Docker image I use.

Answer (score 1):

server.ts

```
const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');
```

Comment: This package is deprecated